# How to query an array for different combinations of ANDs and ORs in MongoDB Aggregation?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregate, logical-operators

I am trying to search for list of students who have completed courses using different combinations of Logical ANDs and ORs.

For example I want to get student who completed ("Course 1" and "Course 2") or "Course 3"

Here is my data structure for each student :

```
{
      "_id" : ObjectId("5c68841cb6b18f31975c8fb0"),
      "courses" :  [ 
           "Course 1", "Course 4"
        ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 
            "courses": {
                $or: {
                    $all: ["Course 1","Course 2"],
                    $in : ["Course 3"]
                 }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

I have tried to nest different operators ( `$all`, `$in`, `$and`, `$or` ) and failed.

Comment: Could you show the sample documents

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `$or` is a top level operator and you have used it in a wrong manner

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$or": [
      { "courses": { "$all": ["Course 1", "Course 2"] }},
      { "courses": { "$in": ["Course 3"] }}
    ]
  }}
])
```

Comment: This query works syntactically but I don't think it gives correct results. I have in my database students that completed both "course 1" and "course 2" . for me it returned only a student who completed "course 3".

Comment: I think I have to use `$all` instead of `$eq`. can you confirm ?

Comment: If you want to get all the students who has completed all the three courses then simply use `{ "courses": { "$in": ["Course 1", "Course 2","Course 3"] }}`

Comment: Could you explain bit more with some sample collection and the output

Comment: change `$eq` to `$all` above and i will accept your answer. https://imgur.com/a/Kvub8wX